# Getting 'Error. An error occurred while processing your request.' while importing a data from excel file to the database in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

When I run my web application on my local server of my computer there is no problem at all but I am getting an error when I publish my web application while trying to import a data from excel file to the database in server.

Error:

'Error. An error occurred while processing your request.'

Connection String:

```
<add name="DatabaseContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=*******;initial catalog=******;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=*****;" />
```

Import Action:

```
if (Session["Name"] != null)
        {
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.                       
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.                       
                        break;
                    default:
                        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Lütfen geçerli bir dosya seçiniz!'); window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/Admin/Index';}, 0);</script>");
                }
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                string conString = string.Empty;

                switch (extension)
                {

                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    default:

                        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Lütfen geçerli bir dosya seçiniz!'); window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/Admin/Index';}, 0);</script>");

                }

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                            //Get the name of First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            connExcel.Close();

                            //Read Data from First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                            connExcel.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.TblYUInfoMember.Add(new InformaticsMember
                        {
                            FirstName = row["Adı"].ToString(),
                            LastName = row["Soyadı"].ToString(),
                            Department = row["Bölümü"].ToString(),
                            Class = row["Sınıfı"].ToString(),
                            Email = row["E-Mail"].ToString(),
                            Phone = row["Telefon"].ToString()


                            //modelID = Convert.ToInt32(row["modelID"]),
                            //EnvantereEklemeTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EnvantereEklemeTarihi"]),
                        });

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Dosyayı kontrol edin!'); window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/Admin/Index';}, 0);</script>");
                        throw;
                    }

                }

                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Lütfen bir dosya seçin!'); window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/Admin/Index';}, 0);</script>");
            }
            return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Başarılı!'); window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/Admin/Index';}, 0);</script>");
        }
```

Comment: You need more debugging information then "Undefiend Error someplace". We can not help you if you do not even know the problem.

Comment: I think you need to have better error tarapping to find exactly where the error is occuring.  It could be the .dll's for Excel file are not installed on your server (I had similar issue in a project I was doing, Excel needed to be installed (or I could re-write my code to use .dll's but they are not installed by default)

Comment: I did notice that you exception handling is extremely questionable. You need to fix that. Here is one article I often link on that mater: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Brad so, should i install the excel to the server ? how can i solve this problem mate is there another solution rather than install excell?

Comment: @Brad btw the excel file which i tried to import is saving on the ftp server but the datas are not importing to the database despite the error...